# Create Flutter Stories like Instagram using custom JSON API

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create stories sections same as the Instagram. I am getting the JSON data from the API.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_instagram_stories

Comment: For now, the package works with Firebase only.
How it works with JSON API response.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/story_view

Comment: List<StoryItem> storyItems = [
    StoryItem.text(...),
    StoryItem.pageImage(...),
    StoryItem.pageImage(...),
    StoryItem.pageVideo(
      ...,
      controller: controller,
    )
________________________________________
unable to play video. Please help

Comment: how to set duration time according to video time